# where is the tmp/setup folder created when doing ADD cmd in docker?

Tags: docker

My dockerfile has this line, it sends the txt file to /tmp/setup folder, but i dont see it anywhere in the current docker folder where Dockerfile sits.

```
ADD requirements.txt /tmp/setup/requirements.txt
```

how do i look inside this folder? where is "tmp/setup" located?

Comment: ADD adds that file under that directory in the docker image. When you run the docker image, it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

This line(`ADD requirements.txt /tmp/setup/requirements.txt`) will copy the file `requirements.txt` from the current folder to the folder `/tmp/setup` in the filesystem of **Docker image** when you building your image. 
You can find this file a folder in the container that run from the built image, not in the current Dockerfile folder.